# Show just some options in in HTML drop down list

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

How can I show 10 option out of 100 in the drop down list and the rest to be available using scrollbar?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this little trick...

```
<select max="2" onmouseover="this.size = 10" onmouseout="this.size = 1">
```

it effectively makes your select drop down into a list on mouse over and puts it back on mouse out.

it's cheating and can mess up your html positioning, but it works.

Edit: I'm pretty sure you can't change the size of the menu displayed when you click a select, this is determined by the browser and not controllable by the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="10">
```

Comment: Actually, you don't really need the "multiple" attribute. It works fine by just setting the size attribute. But I gave you a bump anyway.

Comment: @Robusto interesting, but I think from a readability point of view I'd be inclined to include it to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think `<select multiple="multiple" size="10">` produces a list, not a drop down...