# Keep drop down list scrollbar a fixed height

Tags: html, css

I currently have 3 drop down lists with varying amounts of items in them. Is it possible to keep the scrollable height fixed? e.g if I have 3 items in one list and 8 items in the another list, when I click on either list the drop down part stays the same height. At the moment drop down area of the list with the 8 items is much larger obviously.

```
<select id="picDD1" >
        <option value="0">New Leaf Green</option>
        <option value="1">Air Force Blue</option>
        <option value="2">Grecian Purple</option>
        <option value="3">Antique Gold</option>
        <option value="4">Deep Coral Red</option>
        <option value="5">Yellow</option>
        <option value="6">Pink</option>
        <option value="7">Grey</option>
        <option value="8">White</option>        
</select>

<select id="picDD2">
        <option value="0">Light Weight Aluminium</option>
        <option value="1">High-tech carbon fiber</option>
</select>

<select id="picDD7">
        <option value="0">Basket</option>
        <option value="1">Tail Light</option>
        <option value="2">Bell</option>
        <option value="3">Heavy Duty Lock</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<select id="picDD1" onmouseover="this.size = 3" onmouseout="this.size = 1">
```

got it from here [Show just some options in in HTML drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046904/show-just-some-options-in-in-html-drop-down-list)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I guess this would normally work but since im using a jquery drop down list it wont work...Still learning sorry

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help your requirement. We don't have any scroll controller in `<select>` element in html.

```
<select id="picDD1" size=4>
        <option value="0">New Leaf Green</option>
        <option value="1">Air Force Blue</option>
        <option value="2">Grecian Purple</option>
        <option value="3">Antique Gold</option>
        <option value="4">Deep Coral Red</option>
        <option value="5">Yellow</option>
        <option value="6">Pink</option>
        <option value="7">Grey</option>
        <option value="8">White</option>        
</select>

<select id="picDD2" size=4>
        <option value="0">Light Weight Aluminium</option>
        <option value="1">High-tech carbon fiber</option>
</select>

<select id="picDD7" size=4>
        <option value="0">Basket</option>
        <option value="1">Tail Light</option>
        <option value="2">Bell</option>
        <option value="3">Heavy Duty Lock</option>
</select>
```